# React large array render on svg with drag and select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using React + d3js to render data on svg, i have a large array with data like this

```
const arrayItemExample = {
  id: 1,
  text: 'Some Text for node',
  x: 100,
  y: 300,
  selected: false,
  dragging: false
}
```

The list of such elements can reach tens of thousands. The main problem is that when I click on a rendered element or drag it, I update the data on that element:

```
const handleDragStart = useCallback((id)=>{
  setData(data=>{
    return data.map(item=>{
      if(item.id === id){
        return {
          ...item,
          dragging: true
        }
      }
      return item
    })
  })
},[])

const handleSelect = useCallback((id)=>{
  setData(data=>{
    return data.map(item=>{
      if(item.id === id){
        return {
          ...item,
          selected: true
        }
      }
      return item
    })
  })
},[])
```

Both of these functions work well on a small amount of data, but if there are 100 or more elements on the page, then clicking or dragging the element slows down the page during the redrawing of elements.

Are there any ways to update the data in a specific element with redrawing its only one? I can't use the component's internal state because I need the total data for the selected and draggable elements: for example, I have selected several elements with ctrl , and when I start dragging one of the selected, the other will also have to be dragged

Comment: Could you provide markup? 99% that most of the time you spend to render elements. You can use React.memo to reduce number of affected elements

Comment: can you show how you're rendering these? I assume you `map` over `data` in some way - and if you're using `key`s correctly (it looks like you should have `key={item.id}` here) then altering just one element as you're doing should only cause React to rerender that one child component, which shouldn't be too much of a performance hit. If it's not this then there could be other things slowing this down (like if these callbacks are called many times a second) - but we really need to see more code.